# How to get the member of an object from a list<object>?

Tags: c#

my method GetColumns returns a list of column information object. I need to add only the columnname from the object to the checklistbox. How can i do that. From this commented lin of code i'm getting the class name of the object. How can i bind the dynamic checklistbox with the name stored in the object?  Please Help....!

```
List<Columns> DBList = new List<Columns>();
DBList = metadataobj.GetColumns(clbTables.Items[indexofselectedtable].ToString());
        chklistcolumns = new CheckedListBox();
            for (int j = 0; j < DBList.Count; j++)
            {

                chklistcolumns.Name = clbTables.Items[indexofselectedtable].ToString();
                //chklistcolumns.Items.Add(DBList.ElementAt(j));
                ;
            }
```

this.Controls.Add(chklistcolumns);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties.aspx).

If all of the objects in the list are the same, you can also call [`ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159799.aspx).

Unlike reflection, this will also work with types like DataTables.

Comment: @SLaks 
properties= ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(DBList);
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
   chklistcolumns.Items.Add(property./* What can be given here if i need to addthe value of the objectproperty ColumnName */ );

Comment: @New: I have no idea what you're asking.  Did you look at the properties of `ProeprtyDescriptor`?

Comment: @SLaks Sir, my object has got a property called 'ColumnName'. In the current context i need only that property to add to a checklistbox. I dont know how to get that. Hope u understood my problem now...

Comment: You're still not making sense.  You need to understand what you want to loop over and which values you want.  You may want to call `property.GetValue(someInstance)`.

Comment: @NewBie I think you are asking for something like this... `ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(...)["ColumnName"].Value;` You can index into the `PropertyDescriptorCollection` returned by `ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties`.. Look at the MSDN documentation linked.

Comment: @Quintin How can i index the PropertyDescriptorCollection?

Comment: @NewBie exactly like the example I provided, you can see the MSDN documentation for `PropertyDescriptorCollection` indexer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4htysy3.aspx

Comment: @Quintin i'm able to get the display name of all the properties associated with the column object...but still unable to get the value associated with the single property named ColumnName.

Comment: @New: Why don't you just access the property normally?  If you really want to do it this way, you're looking for the `GetValue` method.

Comment: @NewBie If you can get the `PropertyDescriptor` for the column object then you just need to call `GetValue` passing in the instance of the column object you want to get the value of... `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(...)["ColumnName"].GetValue(...);`